# Why won't my vb.net project recognize its framework?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, crystal-reports, frameworks

So I've been working on the same windows form application for a while now. Recently I added a form that uses crystal reports and a crystal reports viewer. Since the addition any attempt at deployment has been unsuccessful.

When I installed crystal reports, I needed to change the framework of my project from 4.0 client to 4.0. On building my solution I received the following error message:

`WARNING: The version of the .NET Framework launch condition '.NET Framework 4' does not match the selected .NET Framework bootstrapper package. Update the .NET Framework launch condition to match the version of the .NET Framework selected in the Prerequisites Dialog Box.`

Following the message I went to the launch conditions page for my solutions and changed the framework version, but after running another build, the error persists along with a new error:

`An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'`

I'm using VS2010 and I found through other posts that this was known error and was seemingly irreparable. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your setup project and choose View->Launch Conditions.  Under Launch Conditions click on .Net Framework.  Under the properties section, the Version can be clicked on to change it to ".Net Framework 4" from ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile".